# KOMA-Script captionbeside and custom floats

Tags: floats, positioning, captions, koma-script

In a KOMA-Script report, I want to use a custom float for algorithms and display an `algorithmic`-environment with a caption right next to it instead of below. Apart from the fact that I have to wrap the `algorithmic` in a `parbox` to avoid compiler errors, `captionbeside` has a problem with `float`-floats:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{myfigure}{t}{myfigure}
\begin{document}
% Works as expected: Left & Right on same line.
\begin{figure}
    \begin{captionbeside}{Right}Left\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
% Doesn't work: Left on one line, Right below
\begin{myfigure}
    \begin{captionbeside}{Right}Left\end{captionbeside}
\end{myfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

What's the difference between built-in floats and `float` floats? How can I get the `figure`-like result for everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) there's no need for an additional package in order to define new floating environments as it has its own mechanism:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=myfigure,
  types=myfigures,
  float,
  floatpos=t,
  name=My Figure,
  listname={List of my Figures},
  counterwithin=chapter
]{lomf}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}[h]% positioning parameter just for the example
    \begin{captionbeside}{Right}Left\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}

\begin{myfigure}[h]% positioning parameter just for the example
    \begin{captionbeside}{Right}Left\end{captionbeside}
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

The command `\DeclareNewTOC` and its options are explained in [scrguien.pdf](http://texdoc.net/pgf/scrguien.pdf) section 13.5.

Answer (score 3):

The `float` package seems to introduce slight incompatibilities with lots of other packages and classes. Your example works as intended with the [`newfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) package.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement=t]{myfigure}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}[h]% positioning parameter just for the example
    \begin{captionbeside}{Right}Left\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}

\begin{myfigure}[h]% positioning parameter just for the example
    \begin{captionbeside}{Right}Left\end{captionbeside}
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Additional note: KOMA-Script package `scrhack`.